# Trying to remove website url from select pages/posts

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Website: http://www.otislandscapedesign.com/

I am trying to remove the website title from the following selected pages/posts using id: `category-portfolio`, `clients`, `about`, `contact`.

I've tried the following css code unsucessfully:

```
 .postid-576 .gk-logo-text.inverse > span { display: none; }
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `body` tag, you'll see a class containing the page type (page, post, category) and its ID. For example on the Clients page, the class is `.page-id-576`

So for that specific page, the CSS that would hide the title is:

```
.page-id-576 .gk-logo-text.inverse > span {
    display: none;
}
```

You would need to do the same for all pages, just look for the page type+ID class on the `body` tag of each page.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, you just need to add the `!important` keyword to override the existing style declaration in the stylesheet. Here is your final code:

```
 .postid-576 .gk-logo-text.inverse > span {
    display: none !important;
}
```